# Javascript to detect a toolbar is installed

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a web application, some functionality of which is available as a toolbar in a browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome). I am now required to write a functionality in the app to detect if the toolbar is installed or not. 
How can I do that? Javascript, Java, GWT open to any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would say is if you are the creator of the toolbar then maybe you can do something to manipulate the user agent of the browser and then check that with javascript.

Or you can use classid of the object since it is a registered com object and see if you can get an instance of that.

But these are just ideas. I have never tried doing either before.

EDIT: Ok as I was searching some more wouldn't you know that I found an SO post with a similar thought: [Detect if website visitor has toolbars installed eg. Google toolbar using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971724/detect-if-website-visitor-has-toolbars-installed-eg-google-toolbar-using-javascr)

Comment: After reading your answer, had a thought - "META" tag. That's another way to do it. Toolbar adds "META".

Comment: Oh that should be pretty easy then.