# Can JS on a page detect if the user has a toolbar installed?

Tags: javascript, html, malware-detection

If a website visitor has an adware toolbar installed, it executes popups when the visitor comes to my page.

Is there a way to run Javascript on my page that will detect this activity and stop it?  Or, is there a way to detect and redirect the user to a page with removal instructions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971724/detect-if-website-visitor-has-toolbars-installed-eg-google-toolbar-using-javasc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, yes.

It all depends on whether the toolbar is exposing a public variable that javascript can access.  For example, MyToolbar for Chrome, could expose the object, `mt`  then you can just do a

```
if ( typeof mt !== 'undefined' ) { // they have it installed.
```

You would need to research the toolbars, and find whether they expose these or not.